# How to debug the GUI component of DevExpress?

Tags: c#, devexpress

I'm using DevExpress 9.2, there were a very annoying bug in the report designer, specifically the "group field" windows. How can I go into each .dll and change its implementation? Is there a to do so?

Thanks,

Comment: You pay for the source license...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you have a license with source code you are not supposed to do that.

However, you could use .NET Reflector to decompile the respective DLL, fix the bug and compile it again. There are several drawbacks:

- it's not legal if you don't have the source code license;
- .NET Reflector's output can't be compiled right away and requires slight manual adjustments quite often;
- you will loose the original digital signature of the DLL;
- you end up with an unsupported component.

My recommendation is to contact Developer Express for a fix and/or purchase the source code and modify it yourself.

Comment: Yes, I do have license with source code. Could you show me how?

Comment: Dead on.  There's no other option but getting the source.  
Otherwise, I would suggest their support site (support.devexpress.com) - they've always answered questions for me within 24 hours.

Comment: @Chan You have the source code. So what's the problem? If you know where the bug is and how to fix it, just do it. If not, nobody here can seriously help you without a **very detailed** description of the problem, steps to reproduce, etc.

Comment: @Ondrej Tucny: Sorry I forgot to mention, I'm a newbie to C#. I just checked the source code and realized it's a huge library. I'm using Windows form couple times, but the library sources is totally different from what I thought. I did not intend to ask for detailed descriptions, just a brief description would work for me.

Comment: @Chan In that case the “brief description” is: get help from a more senior developer on your team. That will be the most productive way for you and you will learn from him how to approach such situations.

Comment: Finally, if somebody is interested on how to rebuild DLLs from our source code, refer to the article posted her:  http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/kb/p/A609.aspx.